# VB - Different Results With String-Date Concatenation On Different Machines

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, date, string-concatenation

My co-worker and I were debugging an issue when we came across something curious: the same bit of VB code produces a different output on my machine versus his.  We cannot figure out why.

The code:

```
Dim textForMatching = unmatchedRecord.MetaDataString + " - " + unmatchedEvent.StartDate?.ToLocalTime().Date
```

On my machine, the output would be something like `10d775fff794 - 06/15/2023` while on his machine the output is `10d775fff794 - 6/15/2023`.  That leading `0` in my date output is missing from his.

We're in the same time-zone and we're both using the same version of Visual Studio.

Does anyone know why this happens?  It is some localization interplay due to the implicit conversion to a string by using the `+` operator?  Or are there settings on our computers which could be slightly different and lead to this?

Comment: Why are you adding (`+`) a date to a string?

Comment: Use `&` for string concatenation but even then you should call `...Date.ToString(*format?*)`, or interpolate `Dim textForMatching = $"{unmatchedRecord.MetaDataString} - {unmatchedEvent.StartDate?.ToLocalTime().Date}"`, which will call `ToString()` on the date. I don't know what the implicit conversion from date to string will do, best to not leave it to chance.

Comment: Hi @djv yeah not ideal that it was done this way originally :/

Comment: If you're going to use string interpolation, as suggested above, then you specify formats for dates and numbers the same way you do when calling `String.Format`, e.g. `Console.WriteLine($"The date is {Date.Now:d/MM/yyyy}")`.

Comment: *Always* specify the format if you want to be sure it will be in that format, so `unmatchedEvent.StartDate?.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. Also, the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` the sShortDate setting. Is it different on each machine?

I believe this is how it determines the date format to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should study the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-7.0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002361).

Then you'll find:

> Note that the exact output depends on the current culture and the
> local time zone of the system on which it is run.

So, the reason is that you are using different Windows settings for date and time.